# BibLaTeX entry year or date with text in it? The need to avoid a warning

Tags: biblatex, date

Is there a way to use the bibentry for year or date with for example `date = {Around 171}` or `year = {Around 171}` if the year and date of the work is historically not exactly known and to be precise with this fact? So that biblatex will neglect the "Around" and only use "171" for sorting? But of course prints the complete entry in the bibliography.

Or that something like `year = {Vor 171 v.u.Z.}` is possible, which means: "Before 171 B.C." (before 171 before Christ). This would be important for the greek and roman philosophers if one needs to quote them.

The warning looks like this:

```
WARN - legacy year field 'Around 171' in entry 'AurelDerWegzusichselbst' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.
```

Thanks for ideas.

Comment: See the manual (do `texdoc biblatex`, and search for `circa`) - Table 5 especially. There are several ways: `1723~` = `circa 1723`; `1723?` = ` 1723?`; `1723%` = `circa 1723?`. `circa` is a localisation string. The biblatex option `datecirca=true` will be needed. Also from Table 5, `-0170` should give `171 BC` `Vor 171...` etc localisation if `dateera=christian` option is set.

Comment: Thank you Cicada, that seems to solve it. I will look in details to the documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thank you to user `Cicada` who pointed in the comment to the `biblatex Documentation` to `Table 5` where all of my 20 Warnings could be resolved with satifying results in the output.

Description of what I did for it: in the `biblatex` `\usepackage[options]{biblatex}` I set additionally to my option the two options: `datecirca=true` and `dateera=secular` (would be also possible `christian` or `astronomical`).

In the `bibentries` of the `.bib` file, I set:

`date={171~}` for output: "ca. 171"

`date={-0349}` for output: "350 v.u.Z.", and

`date={-0045~}` for output: "ca. 46 v.u.Z.",

with "v.u.Z." means the german secular abbreviation for "BC" (Before Christ), since I had loaded `\usepackage[german]{babel}`.

It is said in the documentation that these special settings only work with the `date` entry and not with the `year`. So I just replaced in my main `.bib` all `year` with `date` via copy-and-paste (respectively search and replace). And that solved the task.

Comment: Please describe the solution for future users.

Comment: Yes, of course. Done.

Comment: Upvoted, thanks!